# Typescript: "Resolve" a conditional type

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following code.

```
type Bar<A> = { f: A };
type Result<A> = { r: A };

function foo<A>(
  f: (o: A, b: A extends object ? Bar<A> : undefined) => Result<A>
) {
  return undefined as any;
}


const func = <A extends object>(b: Bar<A>) => {
  return foo<A>((o: A, typeError: Bar<A>) => {
    return undefined as any;
  })
};
```

And I am getting a (2) type error(s) in the anonymous function on the argument named `typeError`. It it `type undefined/object is not assignable to type Bar<A>`.
Which I find weird, as `A` clearly extends `object`, so we should be in the case where it is not `undefined`, not a union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the compiler will let you specify resolved types on conditional types containing generics, even if it can evaluate the condition.

The simplest work around is to specify the same conditional type or let type inference do the work for you:

```
const func = <A extends Object>(b: Bar<A>) => {
    return foo<A>((o: A, typeError: A extends Object ? Bar<A> : undefined) => {
        typeError.f; // is ok 
        return undefined as any;
    })
};

//Or

const func = <A extends Object>(b: Bar<A>) => {
    return foo<A>((o: A, typeError) => {
        typeError.f; // also ok 
        return undefined as any;
    })
};
```

Comment: What type does typeError actually have in your examples?
I am trying to do a 
`for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(s))`
but v gets type `any`.
My actual code is using a type with a string index signature. `type Schema<A extends object> = { [k in keyof A]: SchemaEntry<A, k> }`

Comment: @Jomik The type of `typeError` is the full conditional type, but when you try to access members you will be able to access the members of `Bar<A>`

Comment: @Jomik If you can add a sample of your actual code, I can have a look at any other problems

Comment: Hopefully this provides enough context.
https://gist.github.com/Jomik/0802bc60a2abd6d6f083a42c659c74c2

Comment: @Jomik could you post a bit more ? `Validator`, `validator` just the signature

Comment: `validator` is foo from the question, where Bar is `Schema`. `Validator` is a class. Don't think that will influence the outcome though. I left my computer, so if you need the actual signatures, it will have to wait till tomorrow :) Thanks!

Comment: Updated the gist with more context
https://gist.github.com/Jomik/0802bc60a2abd6d6f083a42c659c74c2

Comment: @Jomik Sorry for the delay, it's Easter in my neck of the woods :). I'm not sure why that does not work, but maybe a different approach with the same result would work : https://gist.github.com/dragomirtitian/a1586cfb70785f7b7da0ef483dca12cd